# Infinite scrolling in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Am trying to do lazy loading during onscroll. Below is the code:

```
$(window).scroll(   
    function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > ($(document).height() - $(window).height() - 200) && !loadNews)

        {
            loadNews = true;
            loadMoreNewsItems();
        }
    }
);
```

`LoadMoreNewsItems()` does AJAX call and appends the data, on success of AJAX call am setting loadNews flag to false again.

Is the above implementation correct. I have subtracted 200 because of footer block available below newsitems.

When we check, sometimes the user has to scroll till the footer for loading more newsitems. Am checking this on mobile device. What could be the probelm here.

And, sometimes when we scroll fast there are multiple AJAX requests. But, I have added the loadNews flag for avoiding that. But, it does not work either.

Comment: Be careful with the scroll event, it can cause major performance problems: http://ejohn.org/blog/learning-from-twitter/

Comment: You should at least declare `loadNews` before the scroll-function, eg `var loadNews;`. As it is now, you just assign a value to a local variable, which is undefined each time you evaluate it.

Comment: so you are wondering how you can do instant ajax requests, so you can eliminate the time between reaching the bottom page and the content showing up? a request takes time... just show a spinner while loading or something

Comment: You can't do infinite scrolling when you have a footer. How would your users ever view the footer?

Comment: @davidkonrad - `loadNews` isn't local. (At least, not local to the function shown, because it's not declared within that function.)

Comment: @NickyDeMaeyer If you make the footer static on the page and at a higher z-axis, it will stay visible. Then you could add padding if you ever do get to the bottom of the list.

Comment: @Stijn My workdaround somewhat two years ago was to disable or stop autoscrolling when being subjectively "close enough" to the footer. Instead of loading it would show a link to fetch more results in those cases. It shouldn't be any big issue as long as it has been taken into account.

Comment: @Stijn Absolutely positioning footer?

Comment: @JakeMorrison Right, I guess I was blinded by only having seen bad implementations when there's a footer.